# How do you move a sorted function back to the main method?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I made vector called batting filled with doubles in the main method. I sorted the numbers in the sort function and is working fine. When I print the vector from the sort function the vector is sorted but when I print the vector from main after I call the sort function the vector remain unsorted. How can I fix this?

```
    // code above open and parsed in values into vector
    vector<double> batting;
    //batting = < 0.263591 0.30363 0.25 0.28471 0.263441 0.347748 0.294231 0.261538 0.3 0.25 0.242126 0.272366 0.287425 0.242424 0.171717 0.20202 0.181818 0.193548 0.206897 0 >

    cout << "Unsorted: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < batting.size(); ++i){
        cout << batting.at(i) << " ";
    }
    // output: 0.263591 0.30363 0.25 0.28471 0.263441 0.347748 0.294231 0.261538 0.3 0.25 0.242126 0.272366 0.287425 0.242424 0.171717 0.20202 0.181818 0.193548 0.206897 0

    cout << endl;

    sort(batting, batting.size());

    cout << "Sorted: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < batting.size(); ++i){
        cout << batting.at(i) << " ";
      }
    // output: 0.263591 0.30363 0.25 0.28471 0.263441 0.347748 0.294231 0.261538 0.3 0.25 0.242126 0.272366 0.287425 0.242424 0.171717 0.20202 0.181818 0.193548 0.206897 0


inFS.close();



 return 0;
}


void sort(vector<double> playerStats, int vectorSize) {
    cout << "start of sort funciton" << endl;
    double i;
    double j;
    double indexSmallest;
    double temp;  // Temporary variable for swap

    for (i = 0; i < vectorSize - 1; ++i) {
        // Find index of smallest remaining element
        indexSmallest = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < vectorSize; ++j) {
            if (playerStats.at(j) < playerStats.at(indexSmallest)){
                indexSmallest = j;
            }
        }

        // Swap playerStats[i] and playerStats[indexSmallest]
        temp = playerStats.at(i);
        playerStats.at(i) = playerStats.at(indexSmallest);
        playerStats.at(indexSmallest) = temp;
    }
    cout << "Sorted in function: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < playerStats.size(); ++i){
        cout << playerStats.at(i) << " ";}
        // output: 0 0.171717 0.181818 0.193548 0.20202 0.206897 0.242126 0.242424 0.25 0.25 0.261538 0.263441 0.263591 0.272366 0.28471 0.287425 0.294231 0.3 0.30363 0.347748 

    cout <<  endl;
    cout << "end of sort function" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `sort()` function takes its `playerStats` parameter **by value**, so it receives a *copy* of `batting` from `main()`. Any alterations your function makes to its `playerStats` parameter affect only that copy, not the original.

You need to make your function take its `playerStats` parameter **by reference** instead:

```cpp
void sort(vector<double> &playerStats, int vectorSize)
```